# How to get data from DB in C# net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-3.5

I'm new at net core environment, and I must get an data from my database(postgesql),

I have a data in db but i must only get him in json format, 
so at the begining i create a model class with field this same as in db:

```
namespace crud.Models
{
    public class User: DbContext
    {
        public User(DbContextOptions<User> options): base(options) { }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Firstname{ get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Phone{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

after this i create an repository(in this way i create db controllers in java/spring):

```
namespace crud.Service
{
    public interface IUserRepository : IDisposable
    {
        User GetUserById(int id);
        User GetUserByCity(string city);
    }
}
```

and now I don't know what I must going next, I try to implement this interface in service like this:

```
namespace crud.Service
{
    public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {

        public void Dispose()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public User GetUserByCity(string city)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public User GetUserById(int id)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

but i don't now what i must going next, 
can anyone tell me what my service and controller should look like?

ps: my connection to db:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<User>(opt =>
                opt.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("User")));

        }
```

```
  "ConnectionStrings":{
    "User" : "User ID=root; Password=postgres; Host=localhost; Port=5432; Database=postgres; Integrated Security=true, Pooling=true"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the service and repository patterns for ASP.NET MVC-Core, because they are two very important design patterns in .NET applications that interact with data.  The repository will actually interact with your database via the Entity Framework Core (similar to Hibernate).  Your service layer is an abstraction over your repository.  If you're using the Entity Framework Core then your DbContext will represent your database connection.  Through your DbContext you'll interact with entities, which are POCOs (Plain Ole C# Objects)

https://exceptionnotfound.net/the-repository-service-pattern-with-dependency-injection-and-asp-net-core/

But here I'm taking a few liberties.  I'm assuming your DbContext is called MyDbContext and it contains a Users entity. I've simplified a few things.

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(db != null) 
        { db.Dispose();}
    }

    public User GetUserByCity(string city)
    {
        return db.Users.Where(c => c.City.Equals(city).First();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you must create a entity, which is User in your case.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname{ get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Phone{ get; set; }
}
```

Secondly, create the DbContext

```
public class UserContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public UserContext(DbContextOptions<UserContext> options): base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Next, add the UserContext in the Startup.cs

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<UserContext>(opt =>
                opt.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("User")));
```

Lastly, You must inject the UserContext into the UserRepository (using dependency injection) and you can get your data from your database using this UserRepository.

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly UserContext _context;

    public UserRepository(UserContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public List<User> GetUserByCity(string city)
    {
        return _context.Users.Where(u => u.City == city).ToList();
    }

    public User GetUserById(int id)
    {
        return _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.id == id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take some time to look into Entityframework, beign the major ORM (object relational Mapper ) for c# application's https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/

Answer (score 0):

```
static void HasRows(SqlConnection connection)
{
    using (connection)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
          "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories;",
          connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0),
                    reader.GetString(1));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to StackOverFlow, Please Provide explanation of why and how your answer is working. Good Luck